# Check if string starts with any string in list of strings

Tags: r, string

I have a list of word stems, e.g.:

```
stems <- c("fri", "odd", "inspi")
```

I want to see if a word starts with any of those stems, and then return that stem. For example, `"fright"` begins with `"fri"`, so I want to return `"fri"`.

On the other hand, while `"todd"` contains `"odd"`, it does not start with `"odd"`, and so I wouldn't want to return anything.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I've tried `str_starts()` where the pattern argument is a list, but that doesn't seem to work.

### Duplicates are not an issue in my data.

As a minimal example, if my data looks like:

```
dat <- tibble(complete_word = c("fright", "todd", "quirky", "oddly"))
```

I would want to return:

```
dat <- tibble(complete_word = c("fright", "todd", "quirky", "oddly"),
stem <- c("fri", NA, NA, "odd"))
```

Comment: Can you provide a small set of query words and the desired output? Do you want one result per word or one per stem or something else?

Comment: One result per complete word, where it either returns the matching stem or something like `NA`. I'll add an example.

Comment: `stringr::str_match(dat$complete_word, paste0("^", stems, collapse = "|"))[, 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with tidyverse. Use `map` with `str_starts` to get the matching index, if any, from vector `stem`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(idx = map(complete_word, ~ which(str_starts(.x, stems) == 1)), 
         stem = stems[as.integer(idx)])
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  complete_word idx       stem 
  <chr>         <list>    <chr>
1 fright        <int [1]> fri  
2 todd          <int [0]> NA   
3 quirky        <int [0]> NA   
4 oddly         <int [1]> odd
```

Answer (score 3):

From *base* you can use `startsWith` in `sapply` and subset *stems* with the index from `max.col`.

```
. <- sapply(c(stems, ""), startsWith, x=dat$complete_word)
c(stems, NA)[max.col(., "first")]
#[1] "fri" NA    NA    "odd"

#Alternative thanks to @jay.sf
. <- vapply(c(stems, ""), startsWith, x=dat$complete_word, logical(nrow(dat)))
c(stems, NA)[max.col(., "first")]
```

The same using pipes.

```
sapply(c(stems, ""), startsWith, x=dat$complete_word) |>
max.col("first") |>
(`[`)(c(stems, NA), i=_)
#[1] "fri" NA    NA    "odd"
```

Comment: We can use `vapply(c(st, ""), startsWith, x=x, logical(length(x)))` for even more performance, +1 .

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the words to create a logical vector of matching `stems` for each, match `stems` against that vector for each word and then replace empty strings with `NA`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

stems <- c("fri","odd","inspi")
dat <- c("fright","todd","quirky","oddly")

dat %>% 
  map(\(x){str_starts(x, stems)}) %>% 
  map_chr(\(x){ifelse(any(x), stems[x], NA_character_)})
#> [1] "fri" NA    NA    "odd"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `regexpr/regmatches` approach.

```
f <- \(x, st) {
  p <- paste0('^', st, collapse='|')  ## gives e.g. "^fri|^odd|^inspi"
  m <- regexpr(p, text=x)
  replace(rep.int(NA_character_, length(x)), m > 0L, regmatches(x, m))
}

f(dat$complete_word, stems)
# [1] "fri" NA    NA    "odd"

transform(dat, stem=f(complete_word, stems))
#   complete_word stem
# 1        fright  fri
# 2          todd <NA>
# 3        quirky <NA>
# 4         oddly  odd
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(complete_word = c("fright", "todd", "quirky", 
"oddly")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

stems <- c("fri", "odd", "inspi")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
dat %>%
    mutate(stem = {
        m <- outer(complete_word, stems, Vectorize(startsWith))
        stems[rowSums(m * col(m)) * NA^(rowSums(m) == 0)]
    })
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  complete_word stem
  <chr>         <chr>
1 fright        fri
2 todd          NA
3 quirky        NA
4 oddly         odd
```